# AutoMapper - Map model to Dictionary

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map a DTO to `Dictionary<string, object>` using AutoMapper:

```cs
public class SetEmr
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Repeat { get; set; }
    public int RestTime { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```cs
CreateMap<SetEmr, Dictionary<string, object>>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dst, _, context) =>
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Name", src.Name },
            { "Repeat", src.Repeat},
            { "Order", src.Order}
        };
    }));
```

It doesn't work.

> "Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type."

Are there any other ways to implement such a mapping?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Instead, you should use `.ConvertUsing()` for the [type conversion](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html).

```
CreateMap<SetEmr, Dictionary<string, object>>()
    .ConvertUsing((src, dst) =>
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Name", src.Name },
            { "Repeat", src.Repeat},
            { "Order", src.Order}
        };
    });
```

---

**Solution 2**

Credit to @Lucian's comment, AutoMapper does support mapping from [class instance to dynamic/ExpandoObject](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html). Hence, you can directly perform the mapping to `Dictionary<string, object>` without specifying the mapping configuration/rule.

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NZN484)

Comment: Thanks for the solutions! Would it be possible to add ReverseMap so that when the dictionary value is updated, I can simply use automapper to update the original object ("SetEmr")?

Comment: Hi @bobt, if you use Solution 2, you can directly convert from `Dictionary<string, object>` to `object` without the need to specify the `.ReverseMap()`. AutoMapper does support mapping from class instance to dynamic/ExpandoObject and vice versa. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dr2Fpd)

Comment: Thanks much @Yong Shun! I need to use "ConvertUsing" (Solution 1) because my source object is rather complex (it contains a list, and that list needs to be converted to dictionary). Anyway, manual conversion isn't too bad. Thanks again!